# Firebase: Does the bucket owner have access to all data?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am making a To-do Android Application using the Firebase backend. For that, I can use a simple access rule which allows read and write access only when `uid == auth.uid`. However, as the owner of the bucket, I am currently able to see all the to-dos that any user creates. Clearly, this is unexpected behavior. How do I restrict my access to certain data in my own bucket? Or is there any other alternative?

EDIT: More details. The current security rule is as follows

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if uid == auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

I am working with react-native and following [rnfirebase](https://rnfirebase.io/) and used Google Sign-in by this SDK wrapper [here](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin). The code to upload an image to Firebase storage follows the tutorial [here](https://rnfirebase.io/storage/usage#upload-a-file). Here is the snippet in react-native.

```
const reference = storage().ref('black-t-shirt-sm.png');

  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        onPress={async () => {
          // path to existing file on filesystem
          const pathToFile = `${utils.FilePath.PICTURES_DIRECTORY}/black-t-shirt-sm.png`;
          // uploads file
          await reference.putFile(pathToFile);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: The "bucket owner" is a Google authentication user, not a Firebase Authentication user. When you access the bucket via the Google account of the owner, you will indeed have access to all data in there. But that should not be the case when you access it through a Firebase Authentication account. So: please edit your question to show how you access the bucket, as it's really hard to (help you) shoot at the moment. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks. Added my current default security rule and corresponding JS code to upload a test image to firebase.

Comment: I wrote some feedback as an answer below, just to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense:

```
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if uid == auth.uid;
}
```

This allows access to the file if the built-in variable `auth.uid` matches the context variable `uid`. But you never define `uid` anywhere, so the rule always fails. In fact, this should not even save as you have a syntax error by not defining `uid` anywhere before you use it.

Are you saying that with these rules you have a user who is able to see all files? Can you show an example of that?